# VB6 - How to open Chrome?

Tags: shell, google-chrome, vb6

The problem seems to be simple, but all solutions that I found doesn't worked.

I would like to know how to open Chrome automatically, I tried the code below and several other solutions, but when Chrome is completely closed and I try to open, it shows the window, but it does not open any website.

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
    Shell "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe -url https://www.google.com/"
End Sub
```

[image: Chrome crashing]

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't have anything to do with VB6, of course, it's about Chrome command line switches.  Chrome command line switches start with two dashes. So this should work:

```
Shell "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe --url https://www.google.com/"
```

(`Program Files (x86)` if you're running 64 bit Windows, naturally)

But you don't need to specify the switch for the url, this also works:

```
Shell "C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe https://www.google.com/"
```

**EDIT:**

It would actually appear to be that there isn't an 'url' switch for Chrome, so it is proper to simply place the url on the command line on it's own, as in my second shell command above.

Comment: I've tried this too, but it gives the same problem. I did a test of creating a .bat file that opens Chrome, when I run manually it works normal, if I run the .bat through VB6 it also gives the problem.

Comment: I just tried it, works fine for me, either as a bat file or launching Chrome from vb6 code.

Comment: @Anderson Costa: the use of BAT if totally different from use of programmatically. Don't confuse! Use VB6 code, not BAT (as MarkL wrote). Also, are you sure that the Chrome is 64bit?

Answer (score 1):

You should ensure where Chrome.exe is installed. 32 or 64 bit?
You have to check before to run it.

For example, I have a 64-bit computer and Chrome.exe is 32 bit version installed on:

**C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application**

The code below check for both 32/64 bit version:

1. open a new VBP project, on Form1:
2. add a CommandButton, Name: **cmdOpenChrome**
3. add a TextBox, Name: **txtUrl**
4. copy the below code:

---

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare Function ShellExecute Lib "shell32.dll" Alias "ShellExecuteA" ( _
     ByVal hwnd As Long, _
     ByVal lpOperation As String, _
     ByVal lpFile As String, _
     ByVal lpParameters As String, _
     ByVal lpDirectory As String, _
     ByVal nShowCmd As Long) As Long

Public Sub OpenChrome(ByVal pURL As String)
    Dim sChromePath As String
    Dim sTmp As String
    Dim sProgramFiles As String
    Dim bNotFound As Boolean
    '
    ' check for 32/64 bit version
    '
    sProgramFiles = Environ("ProgramFiles")
    sChromePath = sProgramFiles & "\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
    If Dir$(sChromePath) = vbNullString Then
        ' if not found, search for 32bit version
        sProgramFiles = Environ("ProgramFiles(x86)")
        If sProgramFiles > vbNullString Then
            sChromePath = sProgramFiles & "\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
            If Dir$(sChromePath) = vbNullString Then
                bNotFound = True
            End If
        Else
            bNotFound = True
        End If
    End If
    If bNotFound = True Then
        MsgBox "Chrome.exe not found"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    ShellExecute 0, "open", sChromePath, pURL, vbNullString, 1

End Sub

Private Sub cmdOpenChrome_Click()
    OpenChrome txtUrl.Text
End Sub
```

The sample below use many different browsers:

http://nuke.vbcorner.net/Projects/VB60/VB60variousprojects/tabid/79/language/en-US/Default.aspx#OpenURLwithAnyBrowser